# BoxLayout giving unexpected width for custom component

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, boxlayout

I have a custom component that is extremely simple. It has a preferred and maximum size of 100x100 and is simply a red rectangle. I am adding this to a JPanel which is using a box layout. I would expect the size of the custom component to be 100x100, but instead, it is 50x100 (always half the maximum width).

Here is the code:

```java
public class Testing extends JFrame {

    class TestComponent extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            System.out.println(getWidth());
        }

    }

    private JPanel panel;
    private TestComponent testComponent;

    public Testing() {
        super("Testing");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        testComponent = new TestComponent();
        panel.add(testComponent);
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            new Testing().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

This doesn't happen if instead of my custom component I add a JPanel with its preferred and maximum sizes set.

```java
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        // testComponent = new TestComponent();
        // panel.add(testComponent);
        JPanel test = new JPanel();
        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        test.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        test.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel.add(test);
        add(panel);
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a custom component that is extremely simple.

A custom component is responsible for determining its:

1. minimum size
2. preferred size
3. maximum size

You only implement the preferred and maximum sizes.

> But it still doesn't make sense why the component isn't centered and is half the maximum width.

A BoxLayout attempts to respect the minimum and maximum sizes of the component.

The default minimum size is (0, 0), which appears to be causing confusion for the BoxLayout. I'm not sure why. I would say it is a bug/feature of the BoxLayout.

You need to implement the `getMinimumSize()` method. This seems to work:

```
@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(2, 2);
}
```

Note I tried (1, 1) which didn't work. Again, don't know why.

I would suggest that for your case you may want to use:

```
@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return getPreferredSize();
}
```

for both the minimum and maximum methods, since it appears you want the size to be constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I had gotten it to work temporarily and didn't realise it was because of the minimum size. That's super weird, it only seems to work if the minimum width is greater than 1. I assume the same would happen with height if I laid out the elements in a row instead. And yes, I think I will do as you suggested and have the minimum and maximum both return the preferred size. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding methods `getAnyKindOfSize()` is not a good practice at general. Try to add the component inside a nested `JPanel` which uses `FlowLayout`, and then this `JPanel` to your `BoxLayout`-ed panel. Something like this:

```
testComponent = new TestComponent();
testComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

JPanel flowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
flowPanel.add(testComponent);
panel.add(flowPanel);
```

and:

```
class TestComponent extends JComponent {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); //Notice x, y
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is overriding those methods not good practice? I have seen that recommended in a couple of places.
I also wanted the component itself to decide its size, doesn't nesting it within another JPanel make it so that I need to size the JPanel too? I would really like to avoid this.
Surely I should be able to get my custom component to behave similarly to how JPanel behaves?
Also why `fillRect` at 0, 0 and not `getX(), getY()`?

Comment: Ok, I see that it is drawing relative to the component's position, so it should be `0,0,width,height`. But it still doesn't make sense why the component isn't centered and is half the maximum width.

Comment: *Overriding methods getAnyKindOfSize() is not a good practice at general.* - it is a better practice than invoking setPreferredSize(). It is the responsibility of all Swing components to determine their own size (preferred/minimum/maxim). The component knows better than the programmer what these sizes should be. It can make calculations based on Font, Border or any other property that the component uses.

Comment: @camickr Obviously. I am against calling `setAnyKindOfSize` to a component and overriding any of its methods (related to a dimension). Layouts should handle everything. Making a getter method return a constant sounds bad idea in terms of "software design/OOP programming". If I ever wanted a constant-sized component (I would never want that) like OP wants, I would use the setter, not `@Override` the getter. That's my humble opinion in this matter.

Comment: *Making a getter method return a constant sounds bad idea* - agreed. The class is not designed correctly. The dimension of the rectangle should be a property of the class and the sizes should be based on this (and other?) properties. However, it is the responsibility of every Swing components to determine its own sizes. So each component should have some kind of basic implementation of each of the 3 methods so the layout manager can do its job.